# Would tag clouds be useful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it would be interesting to see a [tag cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) on the tag's wiki page depicting all the other tags it has appeared with. For example, I think anyone with edit privs on the [arcobjects tag wiki](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcobjects/info) should be able to add a tag cloud for this tag.

This would show how strongly two tags are associated with each other.  If I click on one of those tags, I would expect to see a list of posts that has both the arcobjects as well as the tag that I clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists in the sidebar on the very page you linked, under **Related Tags** as a simple list of tags ordered by frequency that they appear with the original tag.

I'm not really a fan of tag clouds.

Comment: Ok, yes the Related tags works fine as is, I hadn't realized they were based on appearing together.